# using dredge function generates error in lmer

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, mumin

I am generating different combinations of a model fitted with lmer `global.mod` and using `prdredge` to do it. Here's my code:

```
require(parallel) || require(snow)
clusterType <- if(length(find.package("snow", quiet = TRUE))) "SOCK" else "PSOCK"
clust <- try(makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 4), type = clusterType))
clusterEvalQ(clust, library(lme4))
clusterExport(clust, "lmerDat")

model.set <- pdredge(global.mod, clust,
                   subset = 
                   dc(tmax_sum_gt_35, I(tmax_sum_gt_35^2)) && 
                   dc(tmin_sum_gt_22, I(tmin_sum_gt_22^2)) && 
                   dc(r_spell_lt_p05, I(r_spell_lt_p05^2)) &&
                   dc(r_sum_gt_p95, I(r_sum_gt_p95^2)) &&
                   dc(spei6_harvest.end, I(spei6_harvest.end^2)) &&
                   Irrigation,  m.lim = c(2, NA),
                   rank = AIC, extra = "adjR^2", trace = 2)
```

However, my code after few seconds generates the following error:

```
Error in rval[k + m, retColIdx] <- qrows[[m]] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Do you use the latest version?

Comment: I can double check. I installed the package a while back (2 months)